# What does the for(h=1;h<=(r-1)/9;h=h*3+1) loop mean in 《Algorithms in C part 1-4》p172 shellSort?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, shellsort

I'm studying the Shell sort from Sedgewick [Algorithms in C part 1-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201314525) on p172.

I use `size` (the length of array), not `l` and `r` (start and end);
so my  code is

```
int i,j,h;
int key;
for( h=1;h<=(size-1)/9;h=h*3+1);
for(;h>0;h/=3)
{
    for(i=h;i<size;i++)
    {
        key=num[i];
        j=i;
        while(j>=h&&key>num[j-h];j-=h)
        {
            num[j]=num[j-h];
        } 
        num[j]=key;
    }
}
```

I know all of this. I read [TAOCP](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/taocp.html). I know 1, 4, 13, … is the best sequence (comparable).
But in this position, my code has

```
for(h=1;h<size;h=h*3+1);
```

My question is: why did he write `h<(size-1)/9`?

What does the '`/9`' mean?

Comment: I think the outer loop may be to do with shell sort increment sequence. If you have not already done so I suggest reading [Sedgwick 1996](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/shell/paperF.pdf).

Comment: `/9` means "divide by nine".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop:

```
for (h = 1; h < size; h = h * 3 + 1)
    ;
```

overshoots the size of the array most of the time.  The alternative loop keeps the gap within range.

You can see this for yourself with a trivial test program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline int hs_gap9(int size)
{
    int h;
    for (h = 1; h <= (size - 1) / 9; h = h * 3 + 1)
        ;
    return h;
}

static inline int hs_gap3(int size)
{
    int h;
    for (h = 1; h < size; h = h * 3 + 1)
        ;
    return h;
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        printf("Size: %3d; gap9 = %d; gap3 = %d\n", i, hs_gap9(i), hs_gap3(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Size:   1; gap9 =   1; gap3 =   1
Size:   2; gap9 =   1; gap3 =   4
Size:   3; gap9 =   1; gap3 =   4
Size:   4; gap9 =   1; gap3 =   4
Size:   5; gap9 =   1; gap3 =  13
Size:   6; gap9 =   1; gap3 =  13
Size:   7; gap9 =   1; gap3 =  13
Size:   8; gap9 =   1; gap3 =  13
Size:   9; gap9 =   1; gap3 =  13
Size:  10; gap9 =   4; gap3 =  13
Size:  11; gap9 =   4; gap3 =  13
Size:  12; gap9 =   4; gap3 =  13
Size:  13; gap9 =   4; gap3 =  13
Size:  14; gap9 =   4; gap3 =  40
Size:  15; gap9 =   4; gap3 =  40
Size:  16; gap9 =   4; gap3 =  40
…
Size:  34; gap9 =   4; gap3 =  40
Size:  35; gap9 =   4; gap3 =  40
Size:  36; gap9 =   4; gap3 =  40
Size:  37; gap9 =  13; gap3 =  40
Size:  38; gap9 =  13; gap3 =  40
Size:  39; gap9 =  13; gap3 =  40
Size:  40; gap9 =  13; gap3 =  40
Size:  41; gap9 =  13; gap3 = 121
Size:  42; gap9 =  13; gap3 = 121
Size:  43; gap9 =  13; gap3 = 121
…
Size:  97; gap9 =  13; gap3 = 121
Size:  98; gap9 =  13; gap3 = 121
Size:  99; gap9 =  13; gap3 = 121
```

As you can see, the 'gap3' algorithm returns an initial value of `h` that is larger than the size of the array.  The 'gap9' algorithm returns an initial value of `h` that is smaller than the size of the array.  This saves a little overhead on the loops (saves one iteration of the outer loop, where the middle loop exits on the first cycle without touching the inner loop.

Comment: thank you very much>_<     i get it .                                                 i can also write                                                    for(h=1;(h*3+1)<size;h=h*3+1)